# Erro de Consulta em PHP

Tags: php

Eu estou a tentar fazer um arquivo em php, que consulte a idade da pessoa e que depois mostre, contudo, o $login aparece-me mas a $idade da pessoa não. Gostaria de saber o que estou a fazer de errado.

```
<?php
    include ("sistema/validar_session.php");
    include("config.php");

    $login = "Goncalo";
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dados_usuarios WHERE Login = '$login'");
    $consulta = mysql_fetch_array($select);
    $idade = $consulta['idade'];

    echo "Olá $login a sua idade é de $idade";
 ?>
```

Aqui está a [estrutura da tabela](http://prntscr.com/7iahxo):

Comment: Mostre como esta a tabela do seu Banco de Dados onde mostra a informação do Login do Usuario

Comment: Aqui está o print: http://prntscr.com/7iahxo

Comment: consegue encontrar o erro?

Comment: Gonçalo, insira o trecho relevante do código no corpo da pergunta como texto. Clique em [edit] para tal

Comment: Nesse caso parece que não tem nenhum valor para `idade` nesse registro, não vejo erros no código.

Comment: O registro está sendo localizado? coloque um `var_dump($consulta;)` no final do código pra ver o que aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, provavelmente sua query nao esta trazendo resultados

```
<?php 
include ("sistema/validar_session.php"); 
include("config.php");

$login = "Goncalo";


$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dados_usuarios WHERE Login = '$login'");

if( mysql_num_rows ( $select ) == 0 )
   echo 'O login '.$login.' não foi encontrado';
else
{
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
     echo "Olá ".$login." a sua idade é de ".$row['idade'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

O melhor seria colocar:

```
<?php include ("sistema/validar_session.php"); include("config.php");

$login = "Goncalo";


$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dados_usuarios WHERE Login = '$login'");

$row= mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$idade = $row['idade'];

echo "Olá $login a sua idade é de $idade"; ?>
```

Comment: Você só alterou o nome da variavel